# Spring Boot. Missed /logfile endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a problem with `logfile` endpoint in my spring boot application - it's missed.
This is my application config:

```
server:
  port: 8081

info:
  app:
    name: Foo Service
    component: Foo Service

secret-message: "{cipher}a702d2b5b0c6bc2db67e7d487c6142e7c23254108503d1856ff516d0a64bbd3663a2514a86647dcf8467d042abcb8a6e"

logging:
  file: "target/foo.log"

management:
  context-path: "/actuator"

spring:
  application:
    name: "foo-service"
  boot:
    admin:
      url: http://spring-boot-admin-url:9000
      client:
        health-url: http://app-url:8081/actuator/health
        management-url: http://app-url:8081/actuator
        service-url: http://app-url:8081
        metadata:
          user.name: "${security.user.name}"
          user.password:  "${security.user.password}"
      username: "${security.user.name}"
      password: "${security.user.password}"

security:
  user:
    name: name
    password: password
```

Spring boot starter actuator version is `1.5.2`. Also `/info` and `/health` endpoints works well for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you get an 404 (not found) or 401 (unauthorized)? If the latter is the case, add

```
endpoints:
   logfile:
      sensitive: false
```

Otherwise you may enable the autoconfiguration logging by setting the level to DEBUG and search for "logfile". This may give you some hints if and why the endpoint might not has been enabled.

`logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging=DEBUG`

Comment: Thank you man! With `logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging=DEBUG` it's working now :)

Comment: Just by enabling the debug logging?!? That should not have any influence. Sure that made the point?

Comment: Yep, I did nothing but that. Setting autoconfiguration logging by setting the log level to DEBUG did it for sure.

Comment: It was 404 by the way.

Answer (score 3):

If you get 401 unauthorized, please read this [document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html) first.

> By default all sensitive HTTP endpoints are secured such that only
> users that have an ACTUATOR role may access them. Security is enforced
> using the standard HttpServletRequest.isUserInRole method.
>
> [Tip] Use the management.security.roles property if you want something
> different to ACTUATOR.
>
> If you are deploying applications behind a
> firewall, you may prefer that all your actuator endpoints can be
> accessed without requiring authentication. You can do this by changing
> the management.security.enabled property:
>
> application.properties.
>
> management.security.enabled=false

Answer (score 3):

If what you get is a 404, make sure to add logging.file or logging.path property in application.properties, as stated in [Endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints) (logfile) documentation:

> Returns the contents of the logfile (**if logging.file or logging.path properties have been set**). Supports the use of the HTTP Range header to retrieve part of the log file’s content.

I don't understand why the accepted answer worked, but for most cases, this is the reason why logfile endpoint gives a 404 response.